# SDL_2 load image not working

Tags: c++

So I recently downloaded the SDL_2 libraries and all the components and wanted to create a simple GUI/UI that had a "button" with a picture in it. I've looked up a few guides and I've copied and rewritten a lot of code as well. But the latest code sample that I found that worked was in C which contained no classes and was pretty messy. So I rewrote it into C++ but for some reason, it does not want to load the image.

I've purposely not posted any Destructor or any functions that I'm 99% sure was not causing the issue. To the post, to not make it too long, I believe the error is in the const void clear function, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas on why? Been trying to figure this out for a long time now, thank you for any advise / Help :)

Window.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <SDL.h>

class Window
{
  public:
     Window(const char* title, int width, int height);
    ~Window();

     void getEvents();
     const void clear();

     inline const bool isClosed() { return _closed; }

 private:
   const char* _title = "SDL_6";
   int _width = 480;
   int _height = 720;
   bool _closed = false;
   bool init();

   SDL_Window *_window = nullptr;
   SDL_Renderer *_renderer = nullptr;
   SDL_Surface *_surface = nullptr;
};
```

Window.cpp:

```
#include "Window.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL_image.h>

#define IMG_PATH "D:\\Picture\\Bowser\\star.jpg"

Window::Window(const char *title, int width, int height) :
   _title(title), _width(width), _height(height)
{
   _closed = !init();
}

const void Window::clear()
{
   int w = 120;
   int h = 120;

   SDL_Texture *img = NULL;
   SDL_Rect texr;
   texr.x = 120;
   texr.y = 120;
   texr.h = 120;
   texr.w = 120;

   const char* file = "D:\\Pictures\\bowser\\star.jpg";

   SDL_Surface *IMG_Load(const char* file);

   SDL_RenderClear(_renderer);
   SDL_RenderCopy(_renderer, img, NULL, &texr);

   img = IMG_LoadTexture(_renderer, IMG_PATH);
   SDL_QueryTexture(img, NULL, NULL, &w, &h);

   SDL_RenderPresent(_renderer);
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Window.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Window window("SDL_6", 720, 480);

   while (!window.isClosed())
   {
       window.getEvents();
       window.clear();
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a function declaration: `SDL_Surface *IMG_Load(const char* file);`

Comment: So I need to declare a function called SDL_Surface and not call it. If so, what could that look like?

Comment: You just need to **call** the function like any of the next lines. It's already declared in the header `SDL_image.h`.

Comment: I'll try that, hopfully it'll be able to load png files. :-)

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was to not declare the:
SDL_Surface *IMG_Load(const char* file); but to call it instead, also changed the order of the code in the: const void Window::clear() function. Thank you for the answer O'Neil :-)